# is there any difference between list_head and LIST_HEAD

Tags: list, linux-kernel, grep

`LIST_HEAD` is found in the sys/queue.h file. After using `man list_head`, I get to know about "LIST_HEAD" but not about "list_head".

I'm just curious what are the definitions of `LIST_HEAD` and `list_head`. In which files are these definitions located in the include directory (I tried to use `grep` (grep command to search for the files that include them, but being a noob, it is not of much help)  `grep -hrn 'list_head"` didn't help. is it that both `list_head` and `LIST_HEAD` are meant for two different tasks/functions? what is the difference if any?

Comment: Why is this tagged with `linux-kernel`? `/usr/include/sys/queue.h` is from and for userspace (glibc).

Comment: My mistake. I'm taking about LIST_HEAD and list_head that are defined in include directory within files list_sort.h, types.h, syscalls.h and list.h

Answer (score 2):

struct list_head is the name of a C struct for holding a generic linked list head (pointer to prev and next of same type) - http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/types.h#L185

LIST_HEAD is a name of a macro that defines and initializes a struct list_head whose name is passed as parameter for the macro - http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/list.h#L22

Comment: hi, sorry for being a noob. but if LIST_HEAD intializes list_head why aren't they in th same file. Is it like we need both the header files to use LIST_HEAD? I find the links useful but I want to study more around this area. can you suggest me which way to go

Comment: @huting the struct is defined in types.h because many of the data structures of the kernel include a struct list_head as a field and therefore need the definition in the include files that defines kernel types. However, only source files (typically C files not include files)  that actually initialize such as structure require the definition of LIST_HEAD.

Comment: Up to and including Linux 2.6.35, `struct list_head` was in `<linux/list.h>`. From 2.6.36 onwards, it moved to `<linux/types.h>`. For the reasons, see the commit [Move list types from <linux/list.h> to <linux/types.h>](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=de5d9bf6541736dc7ad264d2b5cc99bc1b2ad958).